# uninitialized constant My_Class::Accessor (NameError) - uppercase accessor

Tags: ruby

When I have something like :

```
class My_Class
attr_reader :A

def initialize(x)
  @A = x
end

def to_s
  A
end
```

end

and then do :

```
v = My_Class.new("some value")
puts v
```

I get an error like :

```
in `to_s': uninitialized constant My_Class::A (NameError)
```

If I change the accessor to start with a lowercase letter it works. Is this a convention I'm not aware of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, any name that starts with an upper case character is a constant. This means that when the interpreter sees your `#to_s` method, it will look for a constant named `A`, not for a method.

You can read more about it here: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#S3

Answer (score 2):

This is just the normal receiverless message send / variable name ambiguity in Ruby.

If you just write

```
A
```

it could be *either* a receiverless message send without arguments *or* a variable (or in this case a constant).

Ruby resolves this by assuming it is a constant.

The solution is obvious: since the ambiguity is with a receiverless no-arguments message send, there are two ways to resolve it: add a receiver or add arguments:

```
self.A
A()
```

Both work just fine.

For a more in-depth explanation and some examples, see

- [*Optional parens in Ruby for method with uppercase start letter?*](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2950956/#2951439)
- [*How does ruby allow a method and a Class with the same name?*](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2985850/#2986338)
- [*Method and variable name is the same*](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3741582/#3741741)

Comment: Thanks for further explaining this.